# Let A and B be nonempty sets such that B ⊆ A. If there exists an injective function from A to B, then there exists a bijective function from A to B.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I think I may understand the proof but I can't visualize it. Can anyone explain this theorem with the help of diagrams?

Comment: Cantor Schroeder Bernstein

Comment: See the [Cantor Schroeder Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Comment: Have you had a look at this proof on Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem#Proof

Comment: No, I know Cantor Schroeder Bernstein's theorem and I can visualize that, however, I am getting confused about this particular one.

Comment: But this is essentially that. There is an injection $B\to A$ (inclusion) and it is given there is an injection $A\to B$.

Comment: If you're getting confused about this particular example, then instead of applying the *statement* of the Cantor Schroeder Bernstein theorem, the thing to do is to walk through the steps of the *proof* of the Cantor Schroeder Bernstein theorem using this particular example. Have you tried that?

Comment: Oh yess! I was so stupid to not realize the fact that if B is a subset of A and A to B is injective then B to A is injective too.